# Uploading Image to AWS presigned post URL using axios

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios

I am trying to upload an image to an S3 bucket using a presigned URL generated using boto3 on Python. I have been using the example python code that was provided in the documentation and was successful (the image got correctly uploaded with the correct Content-Type). However, when trying to do this in Javascript for the purposes of our frontend application, I am really struggling to get it to work.

Here's the example dictionary returned by the backend:

```json
{
    "fields": {
        "AWSAccessKeyId": "AKIAYS3VM3EBIFL7FKE5",
        "key": "posts/623255a762fd9bdfbd13f91a",
        "policy": "<very long string>",
        "signature": "Qvc/sGBHk0uzirzIfR1YmE2kFlo="
    },
    "url": "https://hotspot-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/"
}
```

Here is the *functioning* Python code:

```py
response = <json response object>
object_name = 'playground/example_profile_group.png'

response['fields']['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
# Demonstrate how another Python program can use the presigned URL to upload a file
with open(object_name, 'rb') as f:
    files = {'file': (object_name, f)}
    http_response = requests.post(response['url'], data=response['fields'], files=files)

# If successful, returns HTTP status code 204
print(http_response)
print(http_response.text)
```

Here is the non-functioning Javascript code:

```js
const data = response.data;
let payload = data.fields;
payload['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg';
const file = {
    uri: previewPath,
    name: previewPath,
    type: 'image/jpeg',
};
payload.file = file;
const url = data.url;

console.log(payload, "MY PAYLOAD")

axios({
    method: 'post',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
    url: url,
    data: payload,
})
    .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data, 'uploaded');
    const data = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(
        'error uploading image',
        error.response.data,
    );
    });
})
.catch(function (error) {
console.log(
    'error getting media link',
    error.response.data,
);
});
```

This is the error that keeps getting returned:

```
 error uploading image <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>MalformedPOSTRequest</Code><Message>The body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data.</Message><RequestId>Q0ES6P4QP75YVVED</RequestId><HostId>eowLxSJQD1xP1EfHPnzGSJzXVGpPjurIMhkdwAD22JMvi9zRoFGg6Bq+mnUt/Lu7DNPY80iBDMc=</HostId></Error>
```

I have been stuck on this for an absurd amount of time, and cannot tell what I am doing wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Where is your actual file blob in your JS code? Also, is there a reason you're not using the AWS JavaScript SDK?

Comment: @Phil Sorry, I didn’t include it. Assume response.data has the same data as the example payload I listed at the top of the post.

Comment: @Phil And yes, I’m assigning policies and file size limits on my backend server (using boto3), I’d rather be posting through this presigned POST.

Comment: Yes, that's the response from your pre-signed URL creation but you can't upload a file without having a file to upload

Comment: @Phil The file exists, it’s in another piece of code I didn’t include. I made sure to check for that.

Answer (score 2):

In order to send a `multipart/form-data` request body, you'll need to use a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instance instead of a JavaScript object.

For example

```js
const { url, fields } = response.data;
const payload = new FormData();
payload.append("file", file); // this is the file blob, eg from <input type="file">
payload.append("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");

// add all the other fields
Object.entries(fields).forEach(([ key, val ]) => {
  payload.append(key, val);
});

// No need to manually set content-type header, your browser knows what to do
const { data: result } = await axios.post(url, payload);
console.log("uploaded", result);
```